# HDFS Under replicated blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am using Cloudera Manager Free Edition on my "Cluster" with all services on my single machine.

My machine acts as the datanode,namenode as well as the secondary namenode.

Settings in HDFS related to replication,

```
dfs.replication                                   - 1
dfs.replication.min, dfs.namenode.replication.min - 1
dfs.replication.max                               - 1
```

Still I get under-replicated blocks and hence Bad Health,

The Namenode log says,

```
Requested replication 3 exceeds maximum 1
java.io.IOException: file /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2013_10_21-15_33_53 on client 111.222.333.444
Requested replication 3 exceeds maximum 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.verifyReplication(BlockManager.java:858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:1771)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:1747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1747)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1745)
```

I have altered the values,saved, Deployed Client Configuration, Restarted too. It's still the same.

What property do I need to set to make CM read replication factor as `1` instead of `3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a client setting. Client wants to replicate file for 3 times. Canary test acts as a client. Looks like you have to tune hdfs canary test settings.
Or toy could try to use Cloudera managr and set replication factor prop as final. It would forbid client to change this property.

Answer (score 11):

Change the replication factor directly in a shell

```
hadoop fs -setrep -R 1 /
```

If you have permission problems, what worked for me was to change the replication factor as the user of each file. I had to change the replication factor for oozie files as follows:

```
sudo -u oozie bash
hadoop fs -setrep -R 1 /
```

Repeat for each user which the permissions failed.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue. In my case it was due to missing blocks. Please confirm if that is the case then go to hdfs://hostname:50070 and see the block report. Try to delete or uploads files for which blocks are missing. This should resolve you issue. That is how I resolved mine.

Comment: Ok. So you mean to say the blocks which are entrirely missing? and don't have any copies at all. That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Hi Vusp.. Did my answer help you. If yes then please mark it right.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login using HDFS user `#su - hdfs`
2. Execute this set of commands to fix under replicated blocks in HDFS manually

   ```
   # hdfs fsck / | grep 'Under replicated' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' >> /tmp/under_replicated_files`
   # for hdfsfile in `cat /tmp/under_replicated_files\`; do echo "Fixing $hdfsfile :" ;  hadoop fs -setrep 3 $hdfsfile; done
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ hadoop fs -setrep -R 1 /
```

or

update your `hdfs-site.xml` file property

```
dfs.replication=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, It's not recommendable to hold both secondary namenode and namenode in the same node. Put in separate machine for better results.

Come to your question. I hope you are testing in your same machine. Cloudera mistakenly consider as you have three replicas, that's why this problem showed up. Form a separate cluster it should have a minimum 4 systems.

First check your hdfc configuration in `hdfs-site.xml` has this configuration or not

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>
```

I hope your cluster has 2 or 3 systems, so the rest of the replicas are not replicated properly, so that this problem showed up.

You can resolve this problem. Just open terminal enter this command

```
$ hadoop fs -setrep -R 1 /
```

Now replications overwrites and resolve this problem, or else add few systems either three or more to the existing cluster. It means commission process surely your problem will resolved.